# How should I uninstall/remove Adobe Flash Player in Ubuntu?

Tags: adobe

I've tried to remove Adobe Flash Player with the command line, but with no success. I disabled the two Flash Shockwave plugins in Firefox, 
but I cannot remove it.

What should I do?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, how did you install it?

Comment: From the Adobe Website, as I haven't found a way to do it with the command line...

Comment: You can install it from the partner repositories if you enable them and then you can install it in the normal way. So did you download the `.deb` file and then just use `sudo dpkg -i` on it or something? What was the name of the package/file?

Comment: No. When I downloaded it from the website,  I enabled the software channel xenial-partner

Comment: I downloaded the APT for Ubuntu 10.04+

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In case you installed it using Apt, run this to find the package name:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep flash | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Then you can uninstall the package by

```
sudo apt-get purge package-name
```

In case you copied the plugin so to Firefox plugins, simply delete it from there.

Comment: This command will separate each package on the new line `dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep flash | awk '{ printf $1; printf "\n" }'`

Answer (score 2):

Open synaptic package manager -> find `flashplugin-installer` -> Mark for Complete Removal -> Apply.

Comment: Elder Geek, I've removed this package and it removed the Shockwave  plugin as well from plugins list in my Firefox 53.

Comment: Interesting claim. Which version of Ubuntu did this work on? Which file [in the flashplugin-installer package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/amd64/flashplugin-installer/filelist) do you think is the actual plugin?

Comment: Elementary OS Freya based on Ubuntu 14.04:
Linux linux-desktop 4.4.0-72-generic #93~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 31 15:05:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
After removing flashplugin-installer  Shockwave plugin disappeared. Probably there was dependencies, don't sure about it.
Start-Date: 2017-04-23  19:08:38
Commandline: /usr/sbin/synaptic
Purge: flashplugin-installer:amd64 (25.0.0.148ubuntu0.14.04.1)
End-Date: 2017-04-23  19:08:41

Comment: Your basic assumption that what **ostensibly** works for Elementary OS works for Ubuntu is flawed. If as you say removing that package works for elementary OS you might wish to share that information on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ where you could post both the question and the answer and where it would be on topic and possibly useful to other elementary OS users

Comment: Well, fair enough, in most cases it works vice-versa though.  It's a good advice. I've installed flashplugin-installer right now and plugin appeared again. BTW name of the file for Shockwave Flash (v.25)  is libflashplayer.so. Do you suggest delete my answer?

Comment: Much better. :-)

Comment: @ElderGeek the plugin is removed by the pre-process scripts in Ubuntu as well. Read my answer below for details, and check by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

In reply to Elder's comment: *"Removing the installer package won't remove the plugin"*, I just wanted to clarify that the **pre-processing scripts** of flashplugin-installer package, **does remove** the plugin, as long as you take care of marking it for **Complete Removal** or use "purge" action, as both the answers recommends.

If you want to check, just locate the plugin on your filesystem:

```
$ ll /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/
flashplugin-alternative.so -> /etc/alternatives/mozilla-flashplugin

$ ll /etc/alternatives/mozilla-flashplugin
/etc/alternatives/mozilla-flashplugin -> /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so

$ ll /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
```

Now remove the flash-installer package with:

```
apt-get purge flashplugin-installer
```

and check that the plugin itself has been removed:

```
$ ll /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/
No such file or directory

$ ll /etc/alternatives/mozilla-flashplugin
No such file or directory

$ ll /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
No such file or directory
```

Comment: I have no doubt that purging the package as in the previously accepted answer removes the plugin. I've edited your answer to remove your false assumption. It seems you've misunderstood me, possibly regarding a comment I made regarding Elementary OS.

Comment: No @ElderGeek , I didn't refer to the comment about Elementary OS. I referred to your first comment: "Removing the installer package won't remove the plugin".

Comment: So why are you purging it rather than removing it in your answer if removing the package will remove the plugin?

Comment: I just said that pre-processing scripts will remove the plugin. Of course I refer to the "purge" action as suggested in both answers, and as it seems logic based on the original question. If you want to warn about "remove" action, then I agree: it leaves its configuration files on the system in addition to the plugin downloaded.

Comment: That was exactly my point. Clearly @daGo got the message as the answer was edited and corrected the following day.