# Facebook videos not playing on Mozilla (but working on Youtube) - 16.04

Tags: 16.04, video-player, facebook, mozilla

Facebook videos stopped playing but on youtube everything is still fine.

When I play videos on Facebook I get:

[image]

"Something Went Wrong, we're having trouble playing this video".

I already did:

1) Update

```
sudo apt-get update        # Fetches the list of available updates
sudo apt-get upgrade       # Strictly upgrades the current packages
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  # Installs updates (new ones)
```

2) Restart PC

3) Tried chrome (everything working)

4) Click on **Learn More** - it says I should update and restart my browser.

5) Remove and install *Firefox Web Browser* and *Adobe Flash Plugin* from Sofware Center

6) Completely remove *Firefox* and *Adobe Flash Plugin* as recommended [Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/16763/530032) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/815427/530032)

As nothing has changed, what else should I try?

(Using Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: What happens if you click `Learn More`?

Comment: @AndroidDev it doesnt say the error,  just say that I should restart browser and update it. Very generic.

Comment: Does it work in another browser? Like Chrome for example?

Comment: @AndroidDev I dont have any other browser, but i can install chrome to test it.

Comment: @AndroidDev chrome is working fine

Comment: What is the actual name of the flash package you have installed? (what's the output of `apt-cache search flashplugin`?)

Comment: @Emily , I already solved the problem, however, i dont know exactly how. That's why this question is still opened.

Comment: Hi Vitor, can you enter the command `apt-cache policy adobe-flashplugin flashplugin-installer` in Terminal and add the output to your question? That may help us to figure out whether the issue was with the adobe-flashplugin package, which is different than flashplugin-installer.

Answer (score 6):

Installing ubuntu restricted extras solved this problem for me

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: Prior to installing ubuntu-restricted-extras, did you have a Flash plugin installed, and if so which package was it?

Comment: Yes I have installed adobe-flashplugin and also tried to update it.

Comment: OK! This is really useful to know. So when you installed ubuntu-restricted-extras, which installs flashplugin-installer, did it remove the adobe-flashplugin package? You can check with the command `apt-cache policy adobe-flashplugin flashplugin-installer`

Comment: It seems that I have installed adobe-flashplugin package but not flashplugin-installer. https://pastebin.com/Z5JB1ywF

Comment: NOT installing adobe-flashplugin and applying this solution worked for me.

Comment: also solved my problem on Ubuntu 20.04 on a new install, when other solutions didn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I fix it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

If that's already installed, try to upgrade it:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade adobe-flashplugin
```

Comment: you need to enable canonical partners in other softwares tab of software and updates software

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and this solution works for me.
You can find "Restart with Add-ones disable" in "Help" menu, the firefox will restart with safe mode, check the video works or not, then switch back to see how about it then.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Ubuntu Software Center and search for codecs and install the GStreamer Multimedia Codecs ( GStreamer OpenCV plugins ) it works for me.

Comment: GStreamer OpenCV plugins (*gstreamer1.0-opencv*) is not in the default Ubuntu 16.04 repositories, but it can be installed in Ubuntu 18.04 and later.

Comment: Please provide a better answer than this.